# How to make all fields visible in layer properties?

Tags: arcpy, fields-attributes

In the layer properties and tab fields, I want to make all fields visible!

```
import arcpy
lyrXul = arcpy.mapping.Layer("Limits")
field_info = arcpy.Describe(lyrXul).fieldInfo
for i in range(0, field_info.count): field_info.setvisible(i, "VISIBLE")
arcpy.RefreshTOC()
arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
```

[image: I want my script to do this]

Comment: I think it is only possible when you make feature layer.

Comment: Can you give me an exemple?

Comment: http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/make-feature-layer.htm see last parameter of the tool.

Answer (score 4):

Try using the layer property [field_info](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-classes/fieldinfo.htm), then:

```
field_info = arcpy.Describe(lyrXUL).fieldInfo
for i in range(0, field_info.count):
    field_info.setVisible(i, "VISIBLE")
```

Comment: I edit my previous question because it ain't working for me. Thanx for your help!